# Numeric value[i] in list Python

Tags: python, django, loops, arraylist

In Django template I want get data from some list, example :

In Django template I want get data from some list, example :

```
list pages as data(doc in couch_db):
{
        "_id": "someone",
        "_rev": "someone",
        "is_active": true,
        "priority_questions": 1,
        "answer_<em>3</em>": "test-data3",
        "answer_<em>2</em>": "test-data2",
        "answer_<em>1</em>": "test-data1",
        "answer_<em>0</em>": "test",
        "ask_3": "test-ask3",
        "ask_2": "test-ask2",
        "ask_1": "test-ask1",
        "ask_0": "test-ask",
        "title": "new-test",
        "extra_field_count": "4",
        "priority_3": 4,
        "priority_2": 3,
        "priority_1": 3,
        "priority_0": 1,
        "type": "help"
 }
```

template:

```
{% for page in pages %}
        <div class="box">
            {{ page.title }}
                {% for i in page.extra_field_count %}
                    {{ page.ask_<em>[i]</em> }}
                    {{ page.answer_<em>[i]</em> }}
                {% end_for %}
    {% end_for %}
```

Please help me, if you can

Comment: Building field lookup names on the fly like this isn't common, in my increasingly long-ago Django experience. You might be able to make it work with something like `{% with "answer_<em>"|add:i|add:"</em>" as field_name %}{{ page.field_name }}{% endwith %}` but I make no guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.
But I have another variant. I change insert data in list pages and my template is

```
{% for page in pages %}
       {% for elem in page.2 %}
            {{ elem.1 }}{{ elem.2 }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `<em>` from `page.answer_[i]` and  `page.ask_[i]`.

```
{% for page in pages %}
            <div class="box">
                {{ page.title }}
                    {% for i in page.extra_field_count %}
                        {{ page.ask_[i] }}
                        {{ page.answer_[i] }}
                    {% end_for %}
        {% end_for %}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP has the `<em>` tags in the keys in their example dataset, so I don't think this will help.

Comment: Removed <em> as present in value. Thanks

Comment: The remaining problem is that the template processor won't interpolate the loop variable `i` there - I don't remember offhand whether square brackets have special meaning in Django templates, but if they don't that will end up looking for a field `ask_[i]` rather than `ask_[0]`, etc. It's a little hard to tell what the OP's situation is but I think I'd be trying to simplify the data structure in the view, personally. Or writing a custom template tag.

Comment: wouldnt i act as a key and this would result in a dict lookup?